# What is the reading of 台北(タイペイ)?

Tags: pronunciation, readings

台北 (or 臺北) is the name of Taiwanese city, Taibei, read [tʰaɪ̯³⁵ peɪ̯²¹⁴⁻²¹⁽⁴⁾] in Mandarin. In Japanese, it is normally rendered with the sequence タイペイ. But what is the reading of this sequence? ペイ is obviously none of the systematic 音読み of the character, but does the norm that -エイ ending is pronounced [e:] instead of [ej] still apply? Or does the pronunciation follow the Chinese version, where the diphthong actually exists? In short, タイペ-イ or タイペー?

(If the correct answer is “people actually say たいほく,” that also is accepted. But still, how does one pronounce 台北 if タイペイ?)

Comment: Can you clarify if your question is "How to pronounce タイペイ" or if it is "Is 台北 read タイペイ or タイペー"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If spelled タイペイ, people usually read literally //taipei// instead of a long vowel today.

Basically, エイ for //eː// is an orthographical rule limited to traditional Sino-Japanese words, or those has readings systematically deriving from historical Chinese pronunciations. While タイペイ is certainly a Chinese word, it is merely an occasional transcription of a modern Mandarin word form, in that respect nothing different than recent loan words from European languages, and people just read it out straightforwardly. Edge cases do exist such as [ケツメイシ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketsumeishi), a music group named after Chinese herbal name [決明子](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senna_obtusifolia) "sicklepod seed", which is clearly a Sino-Japanese word, is almost always pronounced //ketsɯmeiɕi//, because it sounds like but another neologism to the majority who don't know such a word.

Whether you reproduce a syllable whose original sound is like [[ej]] using a long vowel or not is completely arbitrary. For example, a PC brand [*acer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Inc.) registers themselves as エイサー, so we read as it is spelled; a cellphone brand [*au*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_(mobile_phone_company)) as エーユー, and we follow it likewise. It makes an interesting mismatch that *au Pay*, the digital wallet service it provides, is pronounced エーユー・ペイ.

How to read kanji word 台北 itself is up to you; either the standard on'yomi たいほく, タイペイ, or タイペー would work, like we cannot decide the sole correct pronunciation of *Appalachia*.

---

What stated above is not applied to the spelling オウ, for which most people would go with //oː// in any context (except in native 大和言葉).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the norm ; "`-エイ ending is pronounced [e:]`" though, 北 is pronounced as 「ペイ」 or 「ペー」 while playing mahjong game among Japanese people borrowing Chinese pronunciation for calling [the wind tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahjong_tiles#Winds). At least to me, pronouncing either pronunciation;「タイペイ」or「タイペー」is fine.

According to one of the most popular guidebook for Japanese travelers : [地球{ちきゅう}の歩{ある}き方{かた}](https://www.arukikata.co.jp/country/TW/), they adopt 「タイペイ」: 台北.

NHK use「タイホク」on [their TV program : 2度目の台湾 タイホク編](http://www.nhk.or.jp/2ndvisit/taihoku/).

According to [コトバンク:「精選版 日本国語大辞典の解説」](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8F%B0%E5%8C%97-558295#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89), the dictionary has hyperlinked both 「タイペイ」 and 「タイペー」to 「たいほく【台北】」.